# Navigate to a certain page of a GridView from an other aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a website with 2 pages, `Master.aspx` and `Detail.aspx`.
In `Master.aspx` there is a Gridview and when I click on a certain row it will redirect to `Detail.aspx`.

The Gridview inside `Master.aspx` implements "pager size", so when the user is inside `Detail.aspx`, I want them to be able to return to `Master.aspx`, precisely in the same page Gridview. To solve this problem I'm using the following JavaScript:

`history.go(-n)`

This allows the user to return to the correct Gridview page, however, it doesn't update the information inside the Gridview (naturally when the user makes changes in `Detail.aspx`).

How can I update the information inside the Gridview appropriately?

Moreover, I noticed that when I click the page buttons of the Gridview they use a `__doPostBack()` function:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1','Page$3')" 
style="color:White;">3</a>
```

Is it possible to use the `__doPostBack` function from `Detail.aspx`, to redirect to a specific page of the Gridview in `Master.aspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When redirecting back to Master.aspx from Default.aspx you can have it go to the correct page index by passing the page index number through the url

```
Response.Redirect("Detail.aspx?id=" + gridview1.PageIndex.ToString()).
```

On Master.aspx you would then have to set the content of gridview1 then do

```
gridview1.DataBind();
gridview1.PageIndex = Request.QueryString("id")
```

Comment: Thank so much. I solve with your solution. Indeed I have also added some other information souch as FilterExpression, SordExpression and SortDirectin of my gridview. This is my little source code:  ` Response.Redirect("Detail.aspx?id=" + gridview1.PageIndex.ToString() + "&SortExp=" + GridView1.SortExpression + "&SortDir=" + GridView1.SortDirection.ToString() + "&filterExp=" + cboFilter.SelectedIndex.ToString() `